# System.PlatformNotSupportedException exception when calling Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom

Tags: c#, assembly.reflectiononly

I am using .NET Core 2.1 to load an assembly calling `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(...)` but am getting a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` exception. [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom?view=netcore-2.1) seems to indicate that it should work. Has this been implemented? If not, are there any alternatives to get exported types from a .NET 4.7.2 assembly using .NET Core?

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName)
'Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName)' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233031
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform."
    Source: "System.Private.CoreLib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(String assemblyFile)"
    TargetSite: {System.Reflection.Assembly ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(System.String)}
```

Comment: It looks like there's [a known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1682) on the documentation GitHub.

Comment: According to https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/typeloader.md you should look at `System.Reflection.TypeLoader`.

Comment: @IanKemp And where is that class to be found? Can't access it in .NET Core 3 targets.

Answer (score 0):

As written above, reflection is not supported yet on .net core.
You can use the experimental use **TypeLoader** from the LAB's repo.

If you want to use the experimental NuGets, you need to follow instructions on:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab (basically adding the NuGet repo - https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab/) and fetch the System.Reflection.TypeLoader.

Don't expect much support though :)